# Display graph for current and previous month data in OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I have a requirement to show the current and previous month TOP 5 records in a graph. The prompts present are Year, Wuarter and Month. Is it wise to pass a variable and subtracting the current month by 1 to get the data of the previous month? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are several options to do so. One option is to create a new measure in the RPD like this: ago(<Measure name>,  <Time Dimension>, 1 ) with 1 for one month. Doing this substraction in the report itself is also an option but isn't the smartest move since you can't reuse the measures and you can get lost in all the things you have created.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to understand the reporting requirement. Also, why do you mention prompts if you only need to show the current and previous month's top 5 records? Could you clarify?